# Tornado web "AttributeError: '_NullFuture' object has no attribute 'add_done_callback' error

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tornado, ubuntu-18.04

I deployed tornado web with these versions.

Ubuntu 18.04
Python 3.11.4
Tornado 6.3.2

Error message:

```bash
[E 230620 15:07:01 http1connection:67] Uncaught exception
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/shippn/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 276, in _read_message
      delegate.finish()
    File "/home/shippn/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/routing.py", line 268, in finish
      self.delegate.finish()
    File "/home/shippn/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2395, in finish
      self.execute()
    File "/home/shippn/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2434, in execute
      fut.add_done_callback(lambda f: f.result())
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  AttributeError: '_NullFuture' object has no attribute 'add_done_callback'
```

Currently, we use Tornado 5.0.2 and Python 3.6.9 versions. We decided upgrade python to 3.11.4 and all packages. I tried versions of tornado from 5.0 to 6.3.2, but couldn't solve.

Comment: Do not override internal code not supposed to be overridden. Work with the api exposed by the framework.